# Configuring Java Heap Size with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, jvm, hadoop-yarn

When I am configuring Yarn there is a `JAVA_HEAP_MAX` environment variable for allocating memory. When I instantiate a Spark worker does the `spark.executor.memory` overwrite this value? Is there any reason I would need to set the Java heap manually via an -Xmx or do the Spark confs deal with this?

Essentially, do I need to set an initial java heap memory allocation that is greater than the memory I will allocate to a spark or does it manage that on default--and what are the use cases of modifying the JVM through environmental variables outside of Spark?

Answer (score 0):

I never did  -Xmx while submitting job. I always use spark.executor.memory and driver.memory. I think it will overwrite.
Some addition configuration/tune spark using 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#compression-and-serialization

like

spark.memory.fraction

Comment: Are you sure that spark.executor.memory and driver.memory overwrite -Xmx?  What about in stand alone mode?